# Magento 2 checkout bad request (400)

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, http-request

When I try to checkout by selecting a payment method and click place order button, I get following error message,

```
"message": "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again."
```

And I see

```
http://www.my-domain.com/rest/mystorepath/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)
```

on browser console.
What could cause this issue? I have disabled SSL on my site too.

Comment: Which Payment Method you are using? Can you check with Bank Transfer?

Comment: Cash on delivery

Comment: Try to disable that & check with Bank Transfer please.

Comment: Same result, still does not work :(

Comment: Means no Shipping Method is working. Table rates or any. Disable all Shipping Methods

Comment: This is general message of handling all exception in magento.  This message is mainly coming when you have error in your custom code. It may be occure because of you handle any event related to sales, or email sending mail, so give detail information about your customization which you have done.

Comment: @nuwaus I got the same error, any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/321123/57334

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this error, it was some misconfiguration of tables.

If you have this issues, please check the tables `sales_sequence_meta`, `sales_sequence_profile` & `sequence_order_1`

`sales_sequence_meta` and `sales_sequence_profile` tables should look like something similar to these.

[image: sales_sequence_meta]
**sales_sequence_meta**

[image: sales_sequence_profile]
**sales_sequence_profile**

And not to forget, if you already have some orders, please insert a record to `sequence_order_1` table above the number of orders.

*Ex : if you have 10 orders, insert a record with 11 or 12 as `sequence_value`*

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was not related to Payment methods at all.

I added `sales_order_place_after` event on my custom module.

There were some kind of error.

Disabling that module solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the checkout error after the migration of data from Magento 1 to Magento2 ,make these tables in the database according to the stores like this table in Magento 2:

- sales_sequence_profile.sql
- sales_sequence_profile.sql
- sales_sequence_meta.sql
- sequence_invoice_2.sq
- sequence_order_2.sql
- sequence_creditmemo_2.sql

Answer (score 0):

This error appears under many different circumstances.

In my case, I just needed to **reindex**. Check `exceptions.log` for

> main.CRITICAL: Exception: Asymmetric transaction rollback.

to confirm that you just need to `reindex`.

Answer (score 0):

Check you error logs. For me it said **Observer XY must implement Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface**

So I had to change my class from

```
class XY
```

to

```
class XY implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
```