# Magento 2 checkout - 400 Bad Request

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am facing below error while placing an order on Magento 2 store with payment method Cash On Delivery.

```
POST http://yoursite.com/rest/ae_en/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)
```

Is there anyone who faced same issue?

Comment: Try `http://yoursite.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information` or `http://yoursite.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information`

Comment: Where should i change this? This is native Magento's cash on delivery method. I tried with Bank Transfer and it didn't worked for that as well.

Comment: Using REST Client u can do that chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html

Comment: you have to find out, what the error message really says. where it is stored, depends on your deploy mode. A good starting point would be to delete var/report and var/log folders, then reproduce the error and see if anything is added in one of the folders

Comment: When enabling display_errors = 1 at .user.ini you got to know the error reason.then you can be able tosolve this

Comment: Hope this can help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142412/magento-2-checkout-bad-request-400

Comment: Just call the URL in your browser and see what you get back. For me the error message was showing.

Answer (score 4):

Please check root_dir/var/report/api folder if exist or root_dir/var/exception.log  file you will get the reason probably.

Answer (score 1):

400 bad request could mean all sort of things. When encountered in the checkout it's usually some required fields that are missing. You should enable developer mode and try to track back the error. Chances are that you will get a 500 server error with an exception that reveals the path.

I've had this error also a couple of times when using the Checkout REST API, and in my case it was a missing phone number from my shipping address. Some checkout modules allow to hide the phone number from checkout and whilst this will pass most validation steps it will throw an exception when trying to save the address. However, this exception might be hard to catch because the API might say something like 'something is wrong' and masking the original exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was troubleshooting checkout errors and this comment helped me reproduce an intermittent issue I was running into (by removing the telephone number for an existing customer address).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is fixed by adding new values in database. You can also try

Goto Magento database and open table sequence_order_1 and set 2 new value to the database like currently if your table shows 10 as last value, so Insert 11, 12 as new values

Comment: how does this fix the issue? is there a code reference where this will prove to address the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I was working on a VM without internet connection.

It worked after I enabled the connection.

---

First I tried to debug it, by opening the URL with the Bad Request 400 in my browser.
It was giving me the error:

"The consumer is not authorized to access% resources."

but that error is still showing, after it works again after I am connected, so dont let you mislead by this.