# Magento 2.3 Multi website Store /rest/australia/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 404 error

Tags: rest-api, payment-gateway, magento2.3.4, 404

I am using the Multi website store, main website USA, second website Australia. Here my issue in Second Website store (Australia) If i try to pay i am getting 404 error, how to solve this error?

[image]

How to solve the rest API error?

Comment: see your error log...

Comment: Transaction valid, the amount received from my payment gateway, but order not created in Magento 2, my exception log : https://justpaste.it/9lqu0

Comment: try one again run all commands and log folder and cache folder

Comment: Still getting the same error